# Contacts won't sync

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, ios

Help - new widow, non-tech - IOS 7 won't sync my contacts; they're on my laptop, but won't appear on my 5S; error says:

`Cannot sync to the iphone because the mail accounts are in use on the iphone. Close the mail account settings on the iphone then sync again.`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. iOS 7 is new territory for most of us, so please report the success or failure of the *answers* you receive by *commenting* on the answer.  (And if an answer does solve the problem, *accepting* it will let others know that it's a valid solution to the problem).

Answer (score 1):

Under iOS 7 this error can often be solved by force quitting the **Settings** app.

- Open the multitasking switch interface by double clicking on the
  **Home** button
- Slide your finger along the app windows until you see the icon for
  the **Settings** app underneath its window
- Quit the **Settings** app by putting your finger on the window above
  the icon and sliding upward until the window disappears.

[image: screenshot of iOS 7 multitasking interface]